# Android ndk-built shared library results in java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-ndk

**Synopsis:**
The library (call it myEngine.so) uses jni to wrap the native c/c++ code and to provide interface to java native methods. I currently build it with `ndk-build` script of the android ndk.

According to the dalvikvm logs, loading `System.loadLibrary( "myEngine" );` is working well, and the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception comes with the message of the following kind: `No implementation found for native LFoo;.myfunc()V`.

**The problem:**
As they recommend [in this FAQ](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_ULE), I checked `nm myEngine.so` output, and it said "no symbols". This looks strange to me, as i've checked all the jni code for `JNIEXPORT` qualifiers, and it's ok.
However, `readelf -Ws myEngine.so` gives me correct(?) symbol table with this function's name unmangled, like this:

```
 Symbol table .dynsym contains 3237 entries:

 Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name

 0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
 1: 0003c0d0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
 2: 0027e078     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12
 ...
 56: 0003d3c9    36 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    7 Java_Foo_myfunc
 ...
```

What could be a problem, and how do I avoid this exception?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a typo to me - note that the error message cribs about not finding "LFoo" whereas your function is "Java_Foo_myfunc". If your package name has LFoo, you need to call your function "Java_LFoo_myfunc".